# fastest way to convert int8 to int7

Tags: c++, c, performance, bit-manipulation

I've a function that takes `int8_t val` and converts it to `int7_t`.

```
//Bit [7] reserved
//Bits [6:0] = signed -64 to +63 offset value
// user who calls this function will use it correctly (-64 to +63)
uint8_t func_int7_t(int8_t val){
    uint8_t val_6 = val & 0b01111111;
    if (val & 0x80)
        val_6 |= 0x40;
    //...
    //do stuff...
    return val_6;
}
```

What is the **best and fastest** way to manipulate the int8 to int7? Did I do it efficient and fast? or there is better way?

The target is ARM Cortex M0+ if that matters

**UPDATE:**

After reading different answers I can say the question was asked wrong? (or my code in the question is what gave wrong assumptions to others) I had the intension to make an int8 to int7

So it will be done by doing nothing because

8bit:

```
 63 = 0011 1111
 62 = 0011 1110
  0 = 0000 0000
 -1 = 1111 1111
 -2 = 1111 1110
-63 = 1100 0001
-64 = 1100 0000
```

7bit:

```
 63 = 011 1111
 62 = 011 1110
  0 = 000 0000
 -1 = 111 1111
 -2 = 111 1110
-63 = 100 0001
-64 = 100 0000
```

Comment: Your mask should really be `0b00111111` as you don't want the "sign bit" to be set unless the original values sign bit was set. And note that you're not really converting anything, you're just truncating basically.

Comment: Before "best and fastest" you need to address *correct*.  For that, however, you need to explain what is supposed to be done with input values that are outside the range that "int7" can represent.

Comment: @JohnBollinger oh i removed the comment that i suppose the user who calls this function he knows he should put data -64 to +63. so no need to go to that safety..

Comment: wat? So just mask with `& ~0x80` (i.e. `& 0x7f`) and be done with it=?

Comment: Alright, @Hasanalattar, does that mean that if the input value is out of range then *you don't care* what the output is?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala i think -63 would be 0b100011 in 7bit signed integer.. and 0b1000110 in 8-bit signed integer.

Comment: @Hasanalattar well, then I suggest that you go read about 2's complement representation in wikipedia.

Comment: I don't really get what your `int7_t` is. Is it a 7-bit two's complement signed type? You're returning a `uint8_t` so what happens with the high bit? In 2's complement all values between -64 and 63 will have the same bit representation in any types that are 7-or-more-bit wide. You sign-extend to a wider type by simply adding the sign bit to the left

Comment: @AnttiHaapala i didnt know that, i meant binary representation... the one i wrote.

Comment: @phuclv the higher bit is reserved for something else. so this function takes a number and shift it to int7_t in a (byte value) .. (common to have byte in uint8_t) ..

Comment: "reserved" doesn't mean anything. The important thing is that you want to clear that bit or leave it as-is. Normally that often mean don't touch it, in which case you simply have nothing to do, just return the whole int8_t value

Comment: @Hasanalattar oops should be `0b100001`, and `0b11000001`

Comment: @phuclv no, if someone called this function: func_int7_t(-63) it should return [0bX1100001]. my question is not involving the 8th-bit. i will deal with it in the bottom of the function before returning the value.

Comment: *'so it will be done by doing nothing because'* - still you accepted an answer that actually does something... There are two of really recommending doing nothing at all (accept phuclv's, he was to answer first...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not concerned about what happens to out-of-range values, then

```
return val & 0x7f;
```

is enough. This correctly handles values in the range `-64 <= val <= 63`.
You haven't said how you want to handle out-of-range values, so I have nothing to say about that.

**Updated to add:** The question has been updated so stipulate that the function will never be called with out-of-range values. So this method qualifies unambiguously as "best and fastest".

Comment: So, -127 (0b10000001) will become 1. Wrong.

Comment: if the initial value is 0x82 (negative) 0x82 & 0x7f is 0x2 so a positive value, this is not ok

Comment: @bruno: Seconded. Your answer seems to be the most succinct way.

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs, -127 is not a supported argument value.  Arguments must be between -64 and 63, per the function specification.

Comment: @bruno, 0x82 also is not a supported argument value.

Comment: @JohnBollinger _val_ is `int8_t` so it can value 0x82, what do you mean ?

Comment: @JohnBollinger Missed OP statement *user who calls this function will use it correctly (-64 to +63)*. In this case yes, that's the most elegant way.

Comment: ife we continue the number of remarks and answers will not be able to be counted on int7 bits ^^

Comment: @bruno, the function specifications require the caller to pass a value in the range -64 ... +63.  This was originally unclear in the question, but it has been updated.  The behavior when the argument is outside that range is unspecified, and therefore cannot be wrong, no matter what it is.

Comment: @JohnBollinger call the function with (-63) should return [0bX1100001] which is -63 in range of 7-bits signed variable. your soloution masks the sign bit and we lose it.

Comment: @Hasanalattar: `-63` is `1111111`, not `1100001`.

Comment: ^^. Moreover, @Hasanalattar, the sign bit of a 7-bit two's complement number is bit 6 (zero based), not bit 7.  The whole point of the exercise is to return a result with bit 7 clear, is it not?

Comment: @JohnBollinger, no and actually i started to feel that this is going to be complicated. calling function with value (-63) which is [0b‭11000001‬] should return [0bX1111111] - again X means i dont care.

Comment: @TonyK 1111111 is 63, -63 is 1000001. \@Hasan alattar no one cares about your code. People read the description which is unclear. There's no defined mapping in the question

Comment: @phuclv: You are right that I was wrong. But you were wrong too! 1111111 is -1 in 7-bit 2's complement, not 63.

Comment: @TonyK yeah I was thinking about the int8_t value. Indeed it's wrong in 7 bit

Answer (score 6):

the faster way is probably :

```
uint8_t val_7 = (val & 0x3f) | ((val >> 1) & 0x40);
```

`val & 0x3f` get the 6 lower bits (truncate) and `((val >> 1) & 0x40)` move the bit to sign from the position 8 to 7

The advantage to not use a *if* is to have a shorter code (even you can use arithmetic *if*) and to have a code without sequence break

Comment: That has to be `((val >> 1) & 0x40`, surely?

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted to post, too... Interesting alternative `0xc0`, it would retain (duplicate) the sign bit in MSB (arithmetic right shift provided, but should be on ARM).

Comment: Or `((val  & 0x80) >> 1)`.  And that avoids the implementation-defined behavior associated with right-shifting a negative number.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I first right shift *then* do the '&' to be independent of the fact it is a signed shift or not, `((val & 0x80) >> 1)` doesn't have the same result if signed shift or not on 8 bit arithmetic (but ofc all is done on _int_)

Comment: @JohnBollinger Either variant is independent of shift type - only mine (`& 0xc0`) is not...

Comment: @bruno Be aware of val being promoted to int before applying `&` operator, masking out possible sign bit afterwards, so you right-shift a non-negative int then...

Comment: How does that follow, @bruno?  If you shift a negative number then you get implementation-defined behavior, period.  In principle, that could be anything (though it must be documented and consistent).  In practice, of course, there are only two likely possibilities, but if you mask first then you avoid that issue completely.  Even though yours very likely works, it is not *strictly* conforming.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Implementation defined or not does not matter if you mask out all other bits than the single relevant one - which *will* be shifted, no matter if arithmetic or logical shift.

Comment: Of course it matters, @Aconcagua.  Although it's surely not the case for the actual target compiler and environment, an implementation's definition of the behavior of a right shift of a negative number could be something you don't expect, such as always producing -1.

Comment: @JohnBollinger `0b11xx` (result of ASR) and `0b01xx` (result of LSR) will both yield the same result after applying ` & 0x0100` - the differing bit (bit 3 in example) is masked away anyway...

Comment: @JohnBollinger doing that I let the compiler to be able to use an instruction doing the shift on 8 bits whatever it is signed or not, just that, useless to search for more :-)

Comment: This is the slowest method of all! So why has it garnered all the upvotes?

Comment: @TonyK the initial question was to rewrite the given code in an other way with the same behavior, so I did, and *after* the question was edited

Answer (score 4):

To clear the reserved bit, just

```
return val & 0x7f;
```

To leave the reserved bit exactly like how it was from input, nothing needs to be done

```
return val;
```

and the low 7 bits will contain the values in [-64, 63]. Because in two's complement down casting is done by a simple truncation. The value remains the same. That's what happens for an assignment like `(int8_t)some_int_value`

**There's no such thing as `0bX1100001`**. There's no undefined bit in machine language. That state only exists in hardware, like the high-Z state or undefined state in Verilog or other hardware description languages

Comment: You mean `[-64,63]`. Or `[-64,64)`.

Comment: @TonyK yes, fixed the typo

Comment: And clearing the reserved bit has exactly the right semantics for inputs in the allowed range. We can see that by looking at the reverse transformation: if we have a 7-bit two's complement representation of a negative number, then sign-extension to 8 bits means adding a leading 1 bit.  That's value-preserving.  Thus, going back the other way just requires ignoring or removing the extra bit.

Comment: func_int7_t(-63) it should return [0bX1100001]. my question is not involving the 8th-bit. [X] = doesnt matter if its 0 or 1! and that comment from me is wrong because it should return [0bX1111110] which is (-63) in (7-bit binary representation)

Comment: it it doesn't matter then why bothering asking this? Just return the value like above. And -63 is **not** 1111110. Did you see that the last bit is zero which indicates an even number? Try opening calculator and you'll see -63 = 1000001 immediately

Comment: you are right. although i put the first answer i saw as correct answer. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Use bitfield to narrow the value and let compiler to choose what sequence of shifts and/or masks is most efficient for that on your platform.

```
inline uint8_t to7bit(int8_t x) 
{ 
    struct {uint8_t x:7;} s; 
    return s.x = x; 
}
```

Comment: Interesting... From standard's point of view, the compiler can chose, though, if it wants to fill the bit field from left to right or from right to left (solely the order of the members must remain the same), so at least in theory, this is not fully portable. Specified toolchain, though, starts filling at MSB, so we're fine... (Actually, I don't know any other either that does not do so - maybe on some BE platform?)

Comment: I use only s.x in code, all compilers I tried (gcc, clang, msvc) optimize usage of that s entirely out.

Comment: @Aconcagua, it doesn't matter how the compiler *represents* the bitfield's value.  No operations used in this approach depend on that for producing the wanted result.  I don't agree that this is *best*, but it will work fine.

Comment: @JohnBollinger The output *is* correct in any case - a compiler chosing to fill the bitfield starting at MSB might need (up to) two additional shifts, though, and the solution might not be the fastest any more... Possibly of theoretical interest only, as mentioned already, I don't know any such compiler either...

Answer (score 1):

> the user who calls this function he knows he should put data -64 to +63

So not considering any other values, the *really* fastest thing you can do is **not doing anything at all**!

You have a 7 bit value stored in eight bits. Any value within specified range will have both bit 7 and bit 6 the same value, and when you process the 7-bit value, you just *ignore* the MSB (of 8-bit value), no matter if set or not, e. g.:

```
for(unsigned int bit = 0x40; bit; bit >>= 1)
//                NOT: 0x80!
    std::cout << (value & bit);
```

The other way round is more critical: whenever you receive these seven bits via some communication channel, then you need to do manual sign extension for eight (or more) bits to be able to correctly use that value.

Comment: I agree that the low-order 7 bits of a valid input are already correct, and that therefore nothing needs to be done to them.  This is in fact the point of the two answers that suggest just masking off the other.  Perhaps, then, doing nothing is indeed best, but that's not consistent with the example code, which forces the other bit clear.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Question now is: Is clearing the bit really a requirement or was that a misunderstanding when the question was asked...

Comment: my soloution in the question is wrong which lead to wrong answers. 
no and actually i started to feel that this is going to be complicated. calling function with value (-63) which is [0b‭11000001‬] should return [0bX1111111] - X means i dont care.

Comment: @Hasanalattar why should it be 1111111? If you use some strange encoding instead of two's complement then you must include the mapping in the question[

Comment: @Hasanalattar, in 7-bit two's complement, `0b1111111` represents -1, not -63.  -63 would be represented as 0b1000001.  If you mean to convert to a sign/magnitude representation then that's a whole different kettle of fish.